# Property 'componentStack' does not exist on type 'string'.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am implementing an ErrorBoundary using Typescript and React

TSLint is showing an error `Property 'componentStack' does not exist on type 'string'`

Here is my code implementation

```js
interface IState {
  info: ErrorInfo;
}

  public state = {
    errorInfo: "",
  };

  public componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
    this.setState({
      errorInfo
    });
  }
  public render() {
    if (this.state.errorInfo) {
      return (
          <p>
            {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}
          </p>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implicitly declare `errorInfo` as  a string here :

```
public state = {
    errorInfo: "",
};
```

So to typescript what is stored in `errorInfo` is a `string`. `componentStack` cannot exist in the `string` that's why you get the error.

You should declare something like :

```
public state: {
   errorInfo: string | { componentStack: Function, },
} = {
    errorInfo: "",
};
```

and complete the description of what's inside `state` object.

Or use `any` if you don't know.

```
public state: any = {
    errorInfo: "",
};
```

Anyway you should test if `componentStack` exists before calling it, in case `errorInfo` is indeed an empty `string`.

```
if (this.state.errorInfo && typeof this.state.errorInfo.componentStack === 'Function') {
    {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}
}
```

Comment: I changed state to be ```js
public state = {
    errorInfo: { componentStack: Function },
  };
```
and this as you said ```jsx `          <p>{this.state.errorInfo && this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}</p>
```

and It worked Thanks so much :))